# Chapterstyle Memoir: Picture on page left, chapter opening on page right

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters, parts

I am working on the layout of my dissertation and I would like to have the following design for all my chapter-openings:

- New chapters should always start on the left page, with a picturepage that contains only an illustration that spreads over the whole left page. Thus, there is no text on this page, only a large illustration. This whole page illustration is different for each chapter.
- On the page to the right of the picturepage (i.e., the next page), the normal chapter opening page with title, chapternumer, etc., should be.

I have been trying a lot to achieve this, but I do not seem to get the picturepage on the page preceding the normal chapter opening. E.g., I tried to set the documentclass to openleft, but I did not succeed to include a picture on the left, and the chapteropening to the right. In the minimal example below, I have tried to use the `\part` as picturepage (let `\part` start on the left page, put picture on it, then let `\chapter` start on the right page). However, the picture does not display on the part page, but on the next page.

Sorry if the latex code is not so neat, I just started to learn it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,showtrims,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\setstocksize{25cm}{18cm}
\settrims{0.5cm}{0.5cm}
\geometry{paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}%%%%
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% To delete white page after part and put the picture on the part page
\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\vfil}


\begin{document}
\openleft  
\part*{Prechappicturepage1}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{% Add picture to current page
  \AtStockLowerLeft{% Add picture to lower-left corner of paper stock
    \includegraphics[width=\stockwidth,height=\stockheight]{art/testimage.eps}}}
\openright      
\chapter{Title ch1}%

\openleft
\part*{Prechappicturepage2}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{% Add picture to current page
  \AtStockLowerLeft{% Add picture to lower-left corner of paper stock
    \includegraphics[width=\stockwidth,height=\stockheight]{art/testimage.eps}}}

\openright    
\chapter{Title ch2}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). I took the liberty of editing your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for editing my post, I will make sure to mark the code as you suggested next time!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need to mess with shipout here, you just need to get on to an even page (for which `memoir` seems to have a command) add the picture then start a new page and do your chapter head.

You may need to fiddle with the cordinates a bit: I added `[demo]` so the example works without the images.

Note that if you specify both `height` and `width` and don't specify `keepaspectratio` then LaTeX will *distort* the image. I left it as you had it, but you probably should only specify one of those.

```
\documentclass[10pt,showtrims,openright]{memoir}


\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\setstocksize{25cm}{18cm}
\settrims{0.5cm}{0.5cm}
\geometry{paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}%%%%
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout


\newcommand\chapimage[1]{%
\cleartoverso 
\noindent\begin{picture}(0,0)%
\put(-60,-600){%
\includegraphics[width=\stockwidth,height=\stockheight]{art/#1}}%
\end{picture}
\clearpage}


\begin{document}

\chapimage{testimage}% don't use extension
\chapter{Title ch1}%


\chapimage{testimage2}
\chapter{Title ch2}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, David! I copied and adapted most of your code above and it works perfectly. I did not manage to get the right coordinates for the picture so I used the eso-pic package (the quality of the picture stays the same I assume? The only disadvantage is that I use an additional package, right?). For the complete code I have now:

Comment: yes I just looked: eso-pic does same; just uses picture mode the same way but calculates the coordinates for you.

Comment: Great, that saves me some calculations :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, David! I copied and adapted most of your code above and it works perfectly. I did not manage to get the right coordinates for the picture so I used the eso-pic package (the quality of the picture stays the same I assume? The only disadvantage is that I use an additional package, right?). 
See below for the  working newcommand:

```
\documentclass[10pt,showtrims,openright]{memoir}


\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\setstocksize{25cm}{18cm}
\settrims{0.5cm}{0.5cm}
\geometry{paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}%%%%
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\newcommand\chapimage[1]{%
\cleartoverso 
\noindent%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{% Add picture to current page
\AtStockLowerLeft{% Add picture to lower-left corner of paper stock
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true, width=\stockwidth]{art/#1}}}%
\clearpage}
\begin{document}

\chapimage{testimage}% don't use extension
\chapter{Title ch1}%


\chapimage{testimage2}
\chapter{Title ch2}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: you don't want `\noindent` now.