# Memoir: Picture opposite part page

Tags: floats, memoir

I've followed

[Chapterstyle Memoir: Picture on page left, chapter opening on page right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108111/chapterstyle-memoir-picture-on-page-left-chapter-opening-on-page-right)

to get a picture opposite the part page in a two-sided document prepared with `memoir`. My document has outer margins that are larger than the inner margins. To use the full width and to get a centered picture opposite the part page, I use the `changepage` package's `adjustwidth` command. However, the picture is not centered although some dummy text I used for testing purposes is. The following MWE illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\setstocksize{29.7cm}{21.0cm} % A4 stock
\settrimmedsize{27.94cm}{21.0cm}{*} % 27.94cm = 11in
\setlength{\trimtop}{0.0cm}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{23.94cm}{12.3cm}{*}
\setlrmargins{1.13cm}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{2.0cm}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{\onelineskip}{6.15cm}{\onelineskip}
\sidecapmargin{outer}
\setsidecaps{\onelineskip}{6.15cm} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\part{First part}
\cleartoverso 
\begin{adjustwidth}{-6.15cm}{} % temporarily use full page width
\lipsum[1] % dummy text for testing, uses full page width
\begin{figure}
  \centering     
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (12,12);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{adjustwidth} % switch back
\part{Second part}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong or overlooking?

Comment: By "opposite to the part page" do you mean on the left where you have the part title on the right? As of now, it seems like you're trying to place the image on the left *after* (and therefore behind or on the back of) the part page.

Comment: Switch the order of `figure` and `adjustwidth` (and fix the typo in `\end{adjust width}`). Also: `memoir` already has the `adjustwidth` environment, so no need to load `changepage`.

Comment: You don't really want this to *float*, do you?

Comment: @Werner: Yes, I want it on the left page. It may look like it's placed after because I put the figure to the left of the second part page. In that sense, my MWE was not quite minimal...

Comment: @jon: Sorry about the typo, that was due to autocorrect and is now fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't want the picture to *float*, but `figure` tells LaTeX to float the contents. This introduces complications it seems best to do without. Moreover, eliminating the `figure` environment solves the centring problem:

[image: centred image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\setstocksize{29.7cm}{21.0cm} % A4 stock
\settrimmedsize{27.94cm}{21.0cm}{*} % 27.94cm = 11in
\setlength{\trimtop}{0.0cm}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{23.94cm}{12.3cm}{*}
\setlrmargins{1.13cm}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{2.0cm}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{\onelineskip}{6.15cm}{\onelineskip}
\sidecapmargin{outer}
\setsidecaps{\onelineskip}{6.15cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\part{First part}
\cleartoverso
\begin{adjustwidth}{-6.15cm}{}% temporarily use full page width
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (12,12);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustwidth}% switch back
\part{Second part}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

If you need a caption, you can use `\captionof{}{}` from the `caption` or `capt-of` packages. (Unless this is another cherry **memoir** has already picked ;).

Comment: I think, myself, that this will look rather odd and it would be better not to change the page layout for this. That is, the double-page spread is now 'off' to my eye.

Comment: Please, remove the `pdftex` option from `hyperref`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I meant to do that and then forgot.

Comment: And if(!) you do want it to float, just put `adjustwidth` inside `figure` (which may be useful to know in other circumstances)....

Comment: @jon But then it might not end up opposite the page it is meant to be opposite. I guess usually it'll work. But it seems to introduce complications for nothing!

Comment: A reasonable concern, indeed. (Hence the 'in other circumstances' ... and, partly, the reason I didn't answer.)

Comment: @cfr: Thanks for your answer. You are right that it looks odd, this is because I have not changed the style of the part page to use the whole page width (which I do in my real document).

Comment: @egreg: Are you suggesting the pdftex option should be removed in general or because it's not relevant to the MWE? If it's the latter, my apologies, but if it's the former, can you please explain why?

Comment: @user1362373 In general; `hyperref` is able to distinguish whether `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex` is being used and to load the appropriate driver. Thus the explicit option limits portability and, since it's not necessary, it's better not to add it. The same is true for `graphicx`. Only special drivers, such as `dvipdfmx` in case you do `latex+dvipdfmx`, are to be explicitly mentioned.

Comment: `@cfr:` Another of memoir's cherries is its `\legend` command for an unnumbered caption.