# Image on opposite \part page

Tags: graphics, formatting, parts

I'm trying to place a picture on the left side of a \part section, basically what has been done here [Memoir: Picture opposite part page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279493/memoir-picture-opposite-part-page), but with a book document class. I'm also using the epigraph package to change my \part command, which works fine.

But there is a BIG problem. When I insert the picture on the left side (even page), the epigraph shows on the picture page and on the part page, it shows twice! I want it to appear only on the part page.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
  \documentclass{book}

  \usepackage[brazil]{babel}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amstext, array}
  \usepackage{gensymb}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \graphicspath{ {Imagens/} }
  \usepackage[section]{placeins}
  \usepackage{addfont}
  \usepackage[default,scale=0.75]{opensans}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \usepackage{anyfontsize}
  \usepackage{lipsum}






  \newcommand*\cleartoleftpage{%
    \clearpage
    \ifodd\value{page}\hbox{}\newpage\fi
  }

  \usepackage{epigraph}


  \titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\filleft\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont\scshape}
    {\fontsize{90}{90}\selectfont\thepart}
    {20pt}
    {\thispagestyle{epigraph}}

  \setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}


  \usepackage{xpatch}
  \makeatletter
  \xpatchcmd\epigraphhead
   {\let\@evenfoot}
   {\let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot}
   {}{}
  \makeatother

  \usepackage{afterpage}

  \newcommand\blankpage{%
      \null
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
      \newpage}








  \begin{document}

  \chapter{One}
  \lipsum
  \cleardoublepage



  \cleartoleftpage

  \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}

  \epigraphhead[450]{BlablablaBlabaBlablablaBlablablaBlablablaBlablabla.\par\hfill\textsc{Blabmaister}}
  \part{Part One}


  \chapter{Two}
  \lipsum


  \end{document}
```

I've already tried afterpage and a lot of other solutions on the web, but none work. Could you please give me a hand?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Note that if you use `example-image-a`, say, then other people will be able to compile your code (which they can't right now).

Comment: @M. Zoubeer  Just curious, why use `book` when `memoir`, which you mention, gives the same results as `book` but with extensions and more flexibility?

Comment: @Peter Wilson because I didn't know `memoir` existed until very late in my writing. I fear converting now could take some time (although I could be wrong).

Comment: Do you know of any way to get the same results when using scrbook/KOMA-script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing this to a more minimal example, I tried following the package `epigraph`'s instructions on page 6. However, exactly the same problem occurs, even without `titlesec` and the custom definitions of page skipping and the fiddling with the `page` counter and so on.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nextpage,epigraph,graphicx}
\makeatletter
% manual 6
\let\@epipart\@endpart
\renewcommand{\@endpart}{\thispagestyle{epigraph}\@epipart}
\makeatother

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\lipsum


\epigraphhead[450]{BlablablaBlabaBlablablaBlablablaBlablablaBlablabla.\par\hfill\textsc{Blabmaister}}
\part{Part One}

\chapter{Two}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: too many epigraphs]

Clearly, the page style is being applied not once, but twice.

It **does** work if we precede the `\epigraphhead` with

```
\cleartooddpage[\thispagestyle{empty}]
```

[image: just one]

but the manual doesn't mention a need to do this.

Nonetheless, this solution can be adapted to place an image on the preceding even page. That is, the following adaption of the manual's example does work.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nextpage,epigraph,graphicx}
\makeatletter
% manual 6
\let\@epipart\@endpart
\renewcommand{\@endpart}{\thispagestyle{epigraph}\@epipart}
\makeatother

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\lipsum

\cleartoevenpage{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\cleartooddpage[\thispagestyle{empty}\includegraphics{example-image-a}]

\epigraphhead[450]{BlablablaBlabaBlablablaBlablablaBlablablaBlablabla.\par\hfill\textsc{Blabmaister}}
\part{Part One}

\chapter{Two}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: image even & epigraph odd]

[Personal motto: nothing is so difficult as with `titlesec`.]

Comment: Thank you cfr! Actually, your solution did **not** worked out of the box, I couldn't add the nextpage package, and even copying the \cleartooddpage from the .py it still showed the quote twice. **But** you posted that if we preceded the ephigraphead with \cleartooddpage[\thispagestyle{empty}] it would do the trick, as it did! Thank you for posting such a detailed answer, this was driving me crazy!