# Empty pages before the full-page illustrations on the odd page before the next chapter

Tags: graphics, chapters

There is an excellent [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108117) to a very similar question already. I tried to adapt it to my use case: 6 1/4" x 9" paper. But doing so added empty pages at the end of each chapter, before the illustrations. What am I doing wrong?

```
    \documentclass[12pt,smallroyalvopaper]{memoir}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[left=0.75in, right=0.875in, top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
    
    \usepackage{mwe}
    
    \newcommand\chapimage[1]{%
    \cleartoverso 
    \noindent\begin{picture}(0,0)%
    \put(-55,-585){%
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\stockwidth,height=0.95\stockheight]{#1}}%
    \end{picture}
    \clearpage}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \chapimage{example-image-a}% don't use extension
    \chapter{Title ch1}%
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \chapimage{example-image-b}
    \chapter{Title ch2}%
    
    \lipsum[2-4]
    
    \chapimage{example-image-c}
    \chapter{Title ch2}%
    
    \lipsum[3-5]
    
    \end{document}
```

[image: prev. page]
[image: next page]

Edit:

This is the output with `\cleartorecto`

[image: two_pages]

Answer (score 0):

You use `\cleartoverso` which moves to the next even numbered page and then you put the figure. Use `\cleartorecto` which will move to the next odd page and then the figure will be output on the odd page; this will also put a blank page before the chapter. It seems to me that you are putting some illustration at the end of a chapter but perhaps it is more usual to put an illustration at the start of a chapter, but it is your design choice.

Perhaps you might think about `memoir's` `openleft` and `openany` options instead of the default `openright` for chapters. If you don't want any empty pages then consider the `openany` class option and `\clearpage` in your code insteadb of the `\clearto...`.

Comment: That fixes the 1st instance, but adds another empty page for the subsequent chapters. Their illustration now has 1x empty page before, and another after. I added the screenshot to the question. And please, I did not make any design choices - this is copied from the linked question. I am merely trying to adapt it to the paper size I have.

Comment: I just tried `\cleartoevenpage` and it seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @SuperAl I have extended my answer.

Comment: @SuperAl I'm not sure what you want the layout to be.

Comment: Same as in the linked question, each chapter begins on an odd page and the preceding empty even page has a full page illustration. I do not want the illustrations to add any more empty pages.

Comment: @SuperAl But if the last page of a chapter is an even one there will be a blank page before the next even page where you want the illustration placed. Is your design criteria that an odd chapter page is always preceeded by an illustration on the preceeding facing even page? If so then this may well require a blank page before the illustration although you say that you do not want the illustrations to add any more empty pages.

Comment: That is exactly what my answer below achieves.

Comment: @PeterWilson -- Desired format seems to be the same as that of *The TeXbook*.

Answer (score 0):

Based on another [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248829/201502) by David Carlisle, I ended up using `\cleartoevenpage`:

```
\newcommand\chapimage[1]{%
\cleartoevenpage 
\noindent\begin{picture}(0,0)%
\put(-55,-585){%
\includegraphics[width=0.95\stockwidth,height=0.95\stockheight]{#1}}%
\end{picture}
\clearpage}
```

Comment: I see no difference in the output of your original MWE with `\cleartoverso` and one with `\cleartoevenpage` substituted.